# how to add organisation chart using highchart in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to add organization chart in angular but getting error when try to load with script and when i am using imports getting below error:

[image]

Please help me on how can I resolve this error and add organization charts in angular. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organization series type was added in Highcharts v7.1.0, so please make sure that you are using some newer version. Also, this series requires Sankey module.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HCSankey from "highcharts/modules/sankey";
import HCOrganization from "highcharts/modules/organization";

HCSankey(Highcharts);
HCOrganization(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-yzjnxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization

**Changelog:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v7.1.0

Comment: thank you for your help, can you please help me on how can i show corresponding Childs on hover of any (parent)node @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @Deepika, Sure, please create another question with `highcharts` tag.